# Create a vector with lenght n with all possible values

Tags: for-loop, vector, self-reference

Im trying to make a vector of length n with pairs of two values (ranging min and max).

For example if n=3, min=1 and max=2

i need vecors of size ranging from 1 to 3 . Each one containing all possible values ranging from min to max.

---

[(1,1)]

[(1,2)]

[(2,2)]

[(2,1)]

[(1,1),(1,1)]

[(1,1),(1,2)]

[(1,1),(2,2)]

[(1,1),(2,1)]

[(1,2),(1,2)]

[(1,2),(2,2)]

[(1,2),(2,1)]

[(2,2),(1,2)]

[(2,2),(2,2)]

[(2,1),(1,1)]

[(2,1),(2,1)]

[(2,1),(2,2)]

[(2,1),(2,1)]

[(1,1),(1,2),(2,1)]

[(1,2),(1,2),(2,1)]... with all possible combinations of a vector of lenght 3
...
#

I have been trying this code, however i dont know how to change the vector lenght for every possible value (of lenght n) and i dont know how to get them in pairs (i,j).

k=[]

for i in range(1,5):

```
for j in range(2,5):

    k.append([i,j])
```